# How do I make an AppleScript with a drop-down menu without Xcode?

Tags: applescript

How do I make an AppleScript that displays a drop-down menu without using Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in concept of a menu in the dialogs-alerts within the AppleScript language.

The closest you could do would be to name some dummy files (in a temporary folder) with the appropriate action and have the user choose the file labeled with the action you wanted to perform.

```
open folder blah
  with selected file bah
    do whatever
```

A horrendous "solution" to a problem that needs a cocoa menu - whether you make it in Xcode or someone else does - **Xcode/IB is the tool that creates a menu**. MacRuby is a nice way to script an app that needs a more full featured UI than AppleScript. You don't need Xcode/IB to ruby up an app from pure script.

You could create a NIB using Interface Builder and script it all using AppleScript, but the nib defines the menu itself - not AppleScript (even if AppleScript can populate or delete the menu items at run time).

Answer (score 12):

One option would be to use [CocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/#documentation)**:

```
set l to {"aa", "bb", "cc"}
set choices to ""
repeat with x in l
    set choices to choices & quoted form of x & " "
end repeat
set dialog to paragraphs of (do shell script "/Applications/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog" & " standard-dropdown --title title --text text --items " & choices)
if item 1 of dialog is "2" then return -- pressed cancel button
item ((item 2 of dialog) + 1) of l
```

[image]

You could also just use `choose from list`:

```
choose from list {"aa", "bb", "cc"} with title "Title" with prompt "Please choose" default items "bb" with multiple selections allowed
```

[image]

---

** The original URL for this Github repo by `mstratman` has changed.  From research it seems **CocoaDialog** has transitioned to an org.  Here are the new changes:

- [URL](https://cocoadialog.com/)
- [Github](https://github.com/cocoadialog)
- [Repo](https://github.com/cocoadialog/cocoadialog) pertaining to the previous answer

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you just need a list to choose from, you could also do

`choose from list listYouDefined with prompt "Choose from the list."`

Google "AppleScript Choose from list".

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question but since the best up-voted answer says in the documentation for CocoaDialog 2:

> Downloads do not work Downloads for cocoadialog 2 are no longer
>   available. This is mostly in part due to the various changes and lack
>   of permanent storage over the years.

and 3 isn't coming till Spring/Summer 18 I was searching for other alternatives and I found [Pashua](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/pashua/):

[image]
(pic taken from the site)

Under the [documentation](https://www.bluem.net/pashua-docs-latest.html) this is called a [`popup`](https://www.bluem.net/pashua-docs-latest.html#element.popup):

```
Example: Using popup
p.type = popup
p.label = Example popup menu
p.width = 310
p.option = Popup menu item #1
p.option = Popup menu item #2
p.option = Popup menu item #3
p.default = Popup menu item #2
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Github [repo](https://github.com/BlueM/Pashua-Bindings)

After using it I found you can install the Pashua.app in your Application directory or you can embed Pashua in your app.  I'm not the author of this but I needed a base solution for a GUI and this wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Xcode for AppleScript. Just open the AppleScript Editor in Applications/Utilities (Finder shortcut for the Utilities folder: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). There is some sample code for dropdown menus on [MacScripter: Dropdown menu](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27331).

Comment: I have already looked at that link. The script requires a NIB/Xcode interface.

Comment: It's a great example of how AppleScript can modify the menu items at run time though :-)

Comment: Yeah, but not exactly what I'm looking for.