# Applescript Dialog

Tags: applescript, ui, dialog

I it possible to make one dialog with multiple dropdown menu and multiple text field using Script Editor (and not Xcode) ?

I know Xcode it's probably the best option but some of the script in my current script won't work with xcode.

Comment: I don't believe the script editor allows that, or even a more sophisticated editor like Script Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [Dialog Toolkit](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#DialogToolkit). It is a scripting addition which can be used in Script Editor:

> ## [Dialog Toolkit Plus v1.0.1 and Dialog Toolkit v2.0.3](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Script_Libs.html#DialogToolkit)
>
> Dialog Toolkit and Dialog Toolkit Plus are ASObjC-based script libraries for showing enhanced dialogs. Add multiple text entry fields, checkboxes, popup menus, radio buttons, path controls, extra buttons and rules to dialogs. Dialog Toolkit v2.0.3 is a compatible update that fixes an issue with macOS High Sierra (10.13), while Dialog Toolkit Plus is an enhanced version that gives greater flexibility but requires macOS 10.10 or later. You can download the libraries and documentation [here](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/Dialog_Toolkit.zip).

Comment: You can add this answer here too: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21658/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-with-a-drop-down-menu-without-xcode

Comment: The above link is broken. Check here 
https://latenightsw.com/freeware/

Answer (score 0):

### **Yes**

**Short Answer:** No.

**Long(er) Answer:** You can't do this with plain AppleScript. But you can most likely do this with [AppleScriptObjC](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/index.html), but trust me this will be much easier in Xcode.

Take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21658/how-do-i-make-an-applescript-with-a-drop-down-menu-without-xcode).